# Orthogonal basis for the Bilinear form given by $H(A,B) = \operatorname{tr}(AB)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been thinking about this for a while and I've found that for the 2x2 case the matrices are just $\{e_{11}, e_{12} + e_{21}, e_{21}, e_{22}\}$ where $e_{ij}$ is the matrix with $1$ on the $ij$ entry, $0$'s everywhere else. However I can't seem to see any patterns with higher orders. I need to find the basis for the $n \times n$ case.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typeset everything in $\LaTeX$. Let me know if I messed anything up.

Comment: You really want to define it as $ \mbox{tr}(A B^T).$ If you want the identity matrix to give $H(I,I) = 1$ you take $\frac{1}{n} \;  \mbox{tr}(A B^T).$

Comment: Well no, the bilinear form I'm given is defined as H(A,B) = tr(AB), not tr(AB^t) unless I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Note that $H(e_{21},e_{21})=0.$

Answer (score 2):

By Sylvester's Law of Inertia, no orthonormal basis is possible, including the 2 by 2 case. In particular, your $H(e_{21},e_{21}) = 0.$

What is possible is to give a collection of matrices as below. There are $n$ matrices of type (A). There are $\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$ matrices of type (B).There are also $\frac{n^2 - n}{2}$ matrices of type (C).

Any two distinct matrices from the total collection of $n^2$ matrices are orthogonal. Given any matrix $\alpha$ of type (A), $H(\alpha, \alpha) = 1.$ 
Given any matrix $\beta$ of type (B), $H(\beta, \beta) = 1.$  However, given any
matrix $\gamma$ of type (C), $H(\gamma, \gamma) = -1.$

(A) all your $e_{ii}$

(B) with all $j < k,$ take $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (e_{jk} + e_{kj})  $$

(C) with all $j < k,$ also take $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (e_{jk} - e_{kj})  $$

See  [SYLVESTER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)

EDIT, FRIDAY: this was a clever assignment, and not something I knew about. We have a quadratic form defined on square matices with real entries, given by
$$  q(M) = \mbox{tr}(M^2).$$
This is positive definite on the linear subspace given by the symmetric matrices, as then $q(M^2) = \mbox{tr}(M M^T)$ which is the sum of the squares of all $n^2$ entries. It is negative definite on the skew-symmetric matrices, as then  $q(M^2) = - \mbox{tr}(M M^T).$  By adding the dimensions, we find that the "corank" of the quadratic form $q$ is $0.$ Finally, any symmetric matrix $M$ and any skew symmetric matrix $N$ are orthogonal, as
$$  \mbox{tr}(M N) =  \mbox{tr}(N^T M^T) = - \mbox{tr}(N M) = - \mbox{tr}(M N),$$ so that $ \mbox{tr}(M N) =0$ here.

> A symmetric matrix A can always be transformed in this way into a
>   diagonal matrix D which has only entries 0, +1 and −1 along the
>   diagonal. Sylvester's law of inertia states that the number of
>   diagonal entries of each kind is an invariant of A, i.e. it does not
>   depend on the matrix S used.
>
> The number of +1s, denoted n+, is called the positive index of inertia
>   of A, and the number of −1s, denoted n−, is called the negative index
>   of inertia. The number of 0s, denoted n0, is the dimension of the
>   kernel of A, and also the corank of A. These numbers satisfy an
>   obvious relation
>
> ```
> $$n_0+n_{+}+n_{-}=n.$$
> ```

The clever part is that we do not really need to talk about the "matrix" of $q,$ which would be an $n^2$ by $n^2$ matrix. To repeat, see [QUADRATIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia#Law_of_inertia_for_quadratic_forms)

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured this out before reading this but glad to have it confirmed :)

Answer (score 1):

You really want to take the definition as 
$$  H(A,B) = \mbox{tr} \; A B^T       $$
in which case your collection of all $e_{ij}$ does indeed give an orthonormal basis.

Comment: That would definitely make life easy but that's not the bilinear form I'm working with.